# Objective C object property ->

Tags: objective-c, object, boolean

I was trying to use a `BOOL` from an object in an `if else` comparison and I got a warning when I wrote `player.isUp` suggesting I use `player->isUp`

Why can't I use dot notation for object BOOLs? And what does `->` mean??

Comment: You can use dot notation with BOOLs.  Please post the code where this BOOL is declared, and used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use dot notation, you need to define isUp as a property of the class that your object belongs to. The arrow is standard C syntax for accessing a value from a struct pointer.

Comment: Also `->` is objc syntax for accessing a iVar.

Comment: Does it actually have a special meaning in objc or is the ivar represented internally as a member of a struct?

Comment: @UIAdam, Objective-C objects are indeed structs under-the-hood, so this isn't not peculiar to ObjC. It's just standard C notation, which is of course valid in Objective-C.

Comment: In Obj-C 2.0, iVars are accessed by name, instead of fixed offset like struct member.

Answer (score 3):

> Why can't I use dot notation for object BOOLs?

You can, provided there is a property declared.

> And what does -> mean??

This is direct member access to the ivar -- it does not use the getter/setter, nor does it use objc messaging. In this case: `object->ivar`, you will likely get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` if `object` is `nil`.